# Just a character reference

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

> What leaves ewe at six,
>   A short start of seven,
>   Steers a flying stick,
>   To refer to Eleven,
>   Princess's small sidekick,
>   Who left one to heaven?

Re-order the answers of the first 5 lines to answer the 6th!

**Hint 1**

> The character is a side character from a book/movie series. The first 5 lines make up the first and last name.

**Hint 2**

> One of the answers requires a single letter change to spell out the name correctly, but the sound of it stays the same. Two of the answers for the first name share a letter, and two of the answers for the last name share a letter.

**Hint 3**

> The order of the lines are 2,1,5 3,4

Comment: Are you saying that the last one is a 5 word answer (or similar)? Or that it's a 5 letter answer (or similar)? I take it we are looking for 6 book or movie characters. I can guess at the 3rd with reasonable confidence and the 5th with almost no confidence. Interesting.

Comment: The answers to the first 5 lines aren't people, just words, that when strung together correctly, make a characters name. Other than forning the name, the lines arent about the character. I'll add hints later on if need be.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Eleven is capitalized, is this a reference to Stranger Things?

Comment: @Parzival Yes, but only as a person. I could have used any female name. I chose the name mainly because it flowed well with the others.

Comment: Re hint 2: do both copies of the shared letter appear in the name?

Comment: Probably it's time for another hint. (Maybe give us the order).

Comment: @anything as in hum and ming sharing a letter and being humming? no. The letter would only appear once

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What leaves ewe at six,

> DUNG? (idk...it leaves a sheep at "six", i.e. behind it)

A short start of seven,

> Mon - short for Monday (@MMAdams)

Steers a flying stick,

> Fletch - a feather on an arrow which steers it

To refer to Eleven,

> Her - Eleven, a girl, from Stranger Things (@Parzival)

Princess's small sidekick

> Gus - one of Cinderella's mice

Following OP's hint of assembling the bits, you get

> MUNDUNGUS FLETCHER, a character from the Harry Potter saga

Who left one to heaven? SPOILERS ABOUT HARRY POTTER...

> not really sure. He did Disapparate during the Battle of the Seven Potters, which directly caused the death of Alastor Moody.

Comment: Correct on all accounts, nice work :]

Comment: Aw while I was sleeping! +1 though

Answer (score 4):

Answer in progress...

What leaves ewe at six:

> **Wool**: reference to [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/australiaandthepacific/australia/12079887/Overgrown-sheep-is-sheared-after-getting-lost-for-6-years.html) female sheep that was sheared after six years.

A short start at seven:

> **Mon**: as MMAdams says above, Monday is shortened to Mon in the first day of the seven days of the week.

Steers a flying stick:

> I don't have a good answer to this yet. Possibly "**yoke**", as in the control stick on a plane? Or "**bow**", in archery...

To refer to Eleven:

> **Her**: According to a comment on the post "I could have used any female name." Thus my guess is this is a way to refer to a female person, hence the pronoun (could also be she).

Princess's small side kick:

> **Ray**: the firefly in Disney's 2009 film The Princess and The Frog.

Who left one to heaven:

> My answers don't seem to make any character name I know of. I will update if I can think of better ones.

Comment: You're right about Eleven and follow that last train of thought regarding the flying stick :)

Answer (score 3):

Extending on above (mostly anything's answer)
What leaves ewe at six:

> Wool - same reason but also 6 is just a common time to shear any ewe

A short start at seven:

> Mon - same reason

Steers a flying stick:

> Also not sure, I think the flying stick is most likely a broom, so "witch" or any given witches name may fit.

To refer to Eleven:

> El - In stranger things El was elevens nickname, I suppose the information about any female name may change this, in which case "her/she/girl" would be best, but perhaps OP meant a large variety of other names, such as "Elenore, Elvis, Ellen, Eileen.

Princess's small side kick:

> Disney princesses sidekick was a good idea but there are many many more. Meeko, Flit, Pascal, Sebastian, Gus, Jaq, Olaf, Flounder, Lumiére, Cogsworth, Mushu.

Comment: You hit the right side kick in your list...now to determine which one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Could the answer be:

> Lemony Snicket

What leaves ewe at six,

> a **lamb** 'leaves an ewe' in a certain sense

A short start of seven,

> **Mon** day is the shortened form of the first day of seven
>  Lamb + Mon = Lemon ?

Steers a flying stick,

> Witch  ?

To refer to Eleven,

> not sure

Princess's small sidekick,

> not sure

Who left one to heaven?

> Each book in A Series of Unfortunate events starts with Lemony Snicket dedicating the book to his wife Beatrice "Darling, Dearest, Dead".

Comment: Besides the interpretation of the second line, I'm not sure how this could fit. But good try!

Comment: You did have the right interpretation of the second line though :)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

What leaves ewe at six,

> milk

Princess's small sidekick,

> toad

Comment: Right direction for your first guess, looking for a name for the second line.